# PHP Storm 7 (Darcula) Highligts quotes in SQL query

Tags: syntax-highlighting, phpstorm

Thats awful, I can't find where I can turn if off!

[image]

The prolem is that PhpStorm detectes quote as Bad Token and Underwaves it.

Comment: *What's* awful? What are you asking? I see the image, what's wrong with it? Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: PHPStorm thinks, that my quotes in SQL queries are bad tokens and I don't know why it's happening and how to fix this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The backticks delimiters for table and column names are not SQL compliant, they're MySQL, hence it's giving an error.

To fix the problem, inject the "MySQL" language into the string. The problem should be resolved.